# what the purpose of $("li:eq(" + i + ")"))

Tags: jquery

From the official Doc, it said that :eq() need a index param,  like this

`var i = "0"   $("li:eq(i)"))` , can not work,

the i is already a string type

so why i need to turn

`"+ i +"`
to a string add pass this param into `$("li:eq(i)"))` , this can work.

so appreciate if can give me some explanation in the official Doc
thanks

Comment: why are you using var when your variable is `i`?

Comment: when do the array traverse,  array.foreach(function( i )) , like this.

Answer (score 1):

`$("li:eq("+i+")")` is different form the function `eq()` the first is a selector, a string the second one is a function that accepts a integer as a param, they are 2 different functionalities

The selector is a string so we append the i variable as a string using concatenation (+), jquery will do a regex on the selector and will take the i variable and eventually will call the `eq()` function(or functionality similar to it)

Comment: but for the selector :eq(), the " + i + " is a string type, and var i = "0"  is a string type too, I edit the question and make it more clearly,  please check the question, so appreciate.

Comment: @allen_Li if you do `$("li:eq(i)"))` the letter i is a string not the i variable, when you do concatenation (using "+i+") you are replacing i with its value

Answer (score 0):

When you write anything under `'` or `"`. It will be treated as a string, no matter whatever you have assigned in it.

As @madalin ivascu said `eq()` and `:eq()` are two different things. For more details check the link [jQuery eq() Method and :eq() Selector](http://www.concretepage.com/jquery/jquery-eq-method-eq-selector).